# Monitor existing cluster using Galera Manager throwing: deployment status error: DB IP address must be provided

Tags: mysql, mariadb, galera

I am trying to monitor my existing galera cluster using galera manager. I installed galera manager and chose **Monitor existing cluster**. I added the ssh keys provided in the manager in the respective nodes. When I add the node and test access, it is showing fine. But clicking on deploy is throwing a deployment status error: **DB IP address must be provided**. I am not sure where to provide the database IP.

[image]

Comment: Please provide the URL of the reference manual for that product.

Comment: @RickJames   The document url is https://galeracluster.com/2021/02/using-galera-manager-to-monitor-your-existing-galera-clusters/

Comment: One if the images there seems to show an IP address for "Node name".

Comment: @RickJames I have already tried that with the AWS private IP and pulic IP. But not working.

Answer (score 0):

Running into the same issue but with a locally hosted cluster (unmanaged - setup before Galara manager).   I get the

deployment status error: DB IP address must be provided

on all three nodes when trying to add them.  The logs make it look like its trying to install galara-3 which it shouldn't need to do for an existing cluster?

It looks like they have acknowledged this as a bug here.
https://github.com/codership/galera-manager-support/issues/15